# NullInjectorError: No provider for /config.json!" Can I inject a variable as a dependency?

Tags: angular, angular7

I received runtime error NullInjectorError: No provider for /config.json!" when trying to set a local variable as a provider dependency.

inside AppModule, I have

```
{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appConfigFactory, deps:  
HttpClient, configUrl], multi: true}
```

where configUrl is

```
let configUrl = '/config.json'
if (environment.production) {
  configUrl = '/config';
}
const appConfigFactory = (http: HttpClient, configUrlInput: string)         
=> {
  return new ConfigService(http, configUrlInput).load;
}
```

I like to know is there a way to allow me to pass the string value configUrl here (although I understand an alternative way to arrange the configUrl is to put it inside ConfigService class)